# email with facebook javascript api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to fetch facebook user **email** for my app. But when I query, the email address is returned as `undefined`.  I am not getting how to deal with it.

Here is my code-

```
<body>
  <script>
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
      console.log('statusChangeCallback');
      console.log(response);

      if (response.status === 'connected') {

        testAPI();
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

        FB.login(function(response) {}, {
          scope: 'email'
        });
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
          'into this app.';
      } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {}, {
          scope: 'email'
        });
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
          'into Facebook.';
      }
    }

    function checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: 'app id',
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access 

        xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
        version: 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });

    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function testAPI() {
      console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        alert(response.name);
        alert(response.email);
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
      });
    }
  </script>
  <fb:login-button perms="email" autologoutlink="true" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
  </fb:login-button>
  <div id="status">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you able to get the email using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `scope` attribute instead of `perms` in the Login Button, so the permission cannot be fetched. Try

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" autologoutlink="true" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2#quickstart

Comment: That's not helping much. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: alert(response.email) is giving message as undefined.

Comment: When you edited the code, did you see the login popup again asking for the `email` permission?

Comment: Replace `FB.api('/me'` with `FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions'` and add an `alert(response.permissions)`. Then check if the `email` permission is present.

Comment: @Tobi I am getting just "[object Object]" as output.

Comment: @SahilMittal Yes. I also got name of the user login in, but not getting email

Comment: @swapnilgandhi It's really difficult for us to explain you! I quit... Ok last try- whever you get `"[object Object]"` you can always check what's inside the object using `console.log` how dont you know this thing!

Comment: @SahilMittal In console I can see that There is permission granted for email.

Answer (score 8):

@Tobi this really saved my day :

```
FB.api('/me
```

Replaced by

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions', function(response) {
        console.log(response.name);
        console.log(response.email);
    });
```

However, I don't understand why the scope of the following code (which is in the facebook documentation) isn't working

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```